# Wordpress admin panel users form how to customize image upload field

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress Admin panel adding user form, I need image upload field creation and saved in database.

Comment: which form is using contact form 7?

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin [User Registration – Custom Registration Form, Login And User Profile For WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/)